# _mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now python msql.connector

Tags: mysql, mysql-python, mysql-connector

I have a function which you can see below. If a run this function i will get the error which you can see in the title, can you help me?

Not long ago i was able to solve this problem with locks, but right now they dont work. I know that it has something to do with my connection but i have no idea how to solve this

```
def insertNewValues(self,uselessInput):
    self.lock.acquire()
    self.connection.reconnect()
    mycursor = self.connection.cursor()


    query=f"SELECT {self.roomSelect(self.roomNames)} ,time FROM alldata ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1"

    mycursor.execute(query,)
    records = mycursor.fetchall()

    oldValues=[elem for elem in records[0]]
    time=self.addMin(oldValues[-1])
    del oldValues[-1]
    newValues=[self.randomIncreaseDecrease(elem) for elem in oldValues]

    query=f"DELETE FROM temp_minutes LIMIT 1"
    mycursor.execute(query,)
    self.connection.commit()
    mycursor.close()

    mycursor = self.connection.cursor() 


    query=f"""
    BEGIN;

    INSERT INTO alldata ({self.roomSelect(self.roomNames)}, time)
    VALUES {*newValues,str(time)};

    INSERT INTO temp_minutes ({self.roomSelect(self.roomNames)}, time)
    VALUES {*newValues,str(time)};

    COMMIT;
    """

    mycursor.execute(query,)


    self.connection.commit()
    mycursor.close()
    self.lock.release()
```

Comment: you have already a transaction in python why do oyu add another also which query runs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is that you cant execute 2 query at the same time. So you basically have to divide the two as you can see below:

```
def insertNewValues(self,uselessInput):
    self.lock.acquire()
    self.connection.reconnect()
    mycursor = self.connection.cursor()


    query=f"SELECT {self.roomSelect(self.roomNames)} ,time FROM alldata ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1"

    mycursor.execute(query,)
    records = mycursor.fetchall()

    oldValues=[elem for elem in records[0]]
    time=self.addMin(oldValues[-1])
    del oldValues[-1]
    newValues=[self.randomIncreaseDecrease(elem) for elem in oldValues]

    query_delete=f"DELETE FROM temp_minutes LIMIT 1"
    mycursor.execute(query_delete,)
    self.connection.commit()
    mycursor.close()

    #here is one part----------------------------------

    mycursor = self.connection.cursor() 
    query_alldata=f"""
    INSERT INTO alldata ({self.roomSelect(self.roomNames)}, time)
    VALUES {*newValues,str(time)};"""

    mycursor.execute(query_alldata,)
    self.connection.commit()

    #here is the second part----------------------------

    mycursor = self.connection.cursor() 
    query_temp_minutes=f"""
    INSERT INTO temp_minutes ({self.roomSelect(self.roomNames)}, time)
    VALUES {*newValues,str(time)};"""
    
    mycursor.execute(query_temp_minutes,)
    self.connection.commit()
    mycursor.close()
    self.lock.release()
```